# Selenium IDE doesnt pick up certain interactions with a site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am mucking around with selenium and trying something out. If you head to :

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/free-tr-4-id/?piid=34979&pbid=517639039

I get the IDE to record and then I click the Size dropdown, select a size, then click add to cart. Problem is - selenium ide picks up none of that.

Can selenium not do this? Or is this interaction simply too complicated for the IDE to pick up. How would you suggest interacting with the Size and add to cart buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nike Store is powered by Flash technologies.  (You can see that by right clicking and observe.  You cannot view source, you only see an option of `About Flash`.)

Selenium is incapable of operating with Flash, ergo, you cannot automate this website with Selenium.

Comment: Well spotted - I had not noticed that - any idea what I could use to automate flash?

Comment: i really hadn't had the need to do it yet, so nope not yet!